# Numpy, multiplication operation? (M[i, j] = a[i] * b[j])

Tags: python, numpy

Okey, so I am trying to become better at cutting out unnecessary loops from my codes, and I always end up with this "problem": I have two arrays A and B, of length I and J respectively, and I want to create an nested array M size (I, J) where M[I, J] = A[i] * B[j], does anyone know a way to do this without a loop? Thanks for any hints or solutions for this!

edit: just typos.

Comment: I think you're looking for `A * B[:, None]`

Comment: thanks! that was exactly it! great!, do you know where I can read about why this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [multiply.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,3,0,2])
b = np.array([1,4,2])

result = np.multiply.outer(a, b)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 1  4  2]
 [ 3 12  6]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 2  8  4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force broadcasting by constructing an *n×1* matrix for `a`:

```
a[:,None] * b
```

This gives us:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,3,0,2])
>>> b = np.array([1,4,2])
>>> a[:,None] * b
array([[ 1,  4,  2],
       [ 3, 12,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  8,  4]])
```